# Beautiful soup element not found exception

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am making a Crawler using Python 3.6 and Beautiful Soup .This is my code

When I run it I get element not found exception , why? What I want to do is select uri and click on the name uri so a new page opens

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
url = "https://www.codechef.com/ratings/all?order=asc&page=3&sortBy=global_rank"


# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

datalist = [] #empty list
x = 488 
for link in soup_level1.find_all('a', id=re.compile(r"^ember")):

    elemnt2222=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ember"+str(493)+"']/td[2]/div[2]/a")

    python_button = elemnt2222
    python_button.click() #click link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to click. Just get href from anchor. Navigate to that URL.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import time

url = "https://www.codechef.com/ratings/all?order=asc&page=3&sortBy=global_rank"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
#Takes some time to load
time.sleep(5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

links = soup.select('div.user-name > a')
for link in links:
  print(link.get('href'))
```

This will give you this result

```
/users/sumeet_varma
/users/fjzzq2002
/users/dreamoon4
/users/y0105w49
/users/nblt
/users/dzhulgakov
/users/uwi
/users/Fcdkbear
/users/austin990301
/users/KADR
/users/adkroxx
/users/kostroma
/users/fhlasek
/users/argos
/users/watcher
/users/nafis
/users/scli
/users/mister
/users/iwiwi
/users/aurinegro
```

After that you can navigate to

> https://www.codechef.com/users/username

Comment: Thanx a lot mate